# SQLite3 doesn't have concat_ws, looking for workaround

Tags: sqlite, concat

I'm trying to concatenate some columns and I would like to use space as my  output string delimiter.

Basically `concat_ws` would be a perfect fit, but it doesn't exist for SQLite3.

I'm inside a `SELECT` already and I'd like to end up with a string that looks like this:

```
col1_val col2_val col3_val
```

I have `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` as my columns, and they may have empty strings as values which I'd not want to delimit.

`col1`, is safely expected to exist, to not be `NULL`, and not be empty.
However either `col2` and `col3` might be empty, and I'd thus want to skip.

I've tried a few different ideas, but all of them seem to end up with double delimiters when a string is empty.

So some expected results:

```
col1_val
col1_val col2_val
col1_val col3_val
col1_val col2_val col3_val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT coalesce(col1, '')
       || CASE
            WHEN coalesce(col1, '') <> ''
                 AND (coalesce(col2, '') <> ''
                       OR coalesce(col3, '') <> '')
              THEN ' '
            ELSE
              ''
          END
       || coalesce(col2, '')
       || CASE
            WHEN coalesce(col2, '') <> ''
                 AND coalesce(col3, '') <> ''
              THEN ' '
            ELSE
              ''
          END
       || coalesce(col3, '')
       FROM elbat;
```